# Blogger: What happens to a blog after a custom domain expires?

Tags: domain-name, blogging

I have a blog at Blogger and I have purchased a custom domain from a third-party provider. On Blogger, I have set the original address *example.blogspot.com* to be redirected to *example.cz*.
Now, let's say I die tomorrow (after a meteorite falls on my house). After a year or so, the third-party domain expires and no longer exists or worse, someone else buys it. Will *example.blogspot.com* be redirected to *example.cz* even after the domain is expired and will my blog therefore become inaccessible and lost forever? Or can Blogger tell somehow that the domain has expired and will disable the redirection automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

Your blog content now lives at *example.cz* and when it expires, its content falls into a bit bucket, never to be seen again (except, perhaps, via the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/)). [Blogger has a help article](https://support.google.com/blogger/forum/AAAAY7oIW-wofQ6Jd7lU30?hl=en) on this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there's no way Blogger will disable the redirection automatically, is there?

Comment: It does not; designate someone as an emergency contact w/ Google and provide instructions ('IN CASE OF METEORITE'), or prepay the domain far in advance. A better place to ask this class of question would be at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/  , since Blogger is an app which lives in the Cloud.